# NodeJS, gRPC and Kubernetes

Tags: node.js, docker, kubernetes, grpc, grpc-js

I have created a headless service in kubernetes for gRPC server pods.

```
# Express server: acts as client for gRPC server
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: bbl-org-client
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: bbl-org-client
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: bbl-org-client
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: bbl-org-client
          image: sk10/bbl-org-client-service:fbbcc26-dirty
          resources:
            limits:
              memory: "256Mi"
              cpu: "0.1"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: bbl-org-client
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: bbl-org-client
  ports:
    - name: bbl-org-client
      protocol: TCP
      port: 3000
      targetPort: 8080
---
# Babble gRPC server
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: bbl-org-server
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: bbl-org-server
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: bbl-org-server
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: bbl-org-server
          image: sk10/bbl-org-server-service:fbbcc26-dirty
          resources:
            limits:
              memory: "256Mi"
              cpu: "0.1"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata: 
  name: bbl-org-server
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
    app: bbl-org-server
  ports:
    - name: bbl-org-server
      protocol: TCP
      port: 50051
      targetPort: 50051
---
# Mongo DB
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: babble-org-mongo
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: babble-org-mongo
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: babble-org-mongo
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: babble-org-mongo
          image: mongo
          resources:
            limits:
              memory: "256Mi"
              cpu: "0.1"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: babble-org-mongo
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: babble-org-mongo
  ports:
    - name: db
      protocol: TCP
      port: 27017
      targetPort: 27017
```

and my client connection code is

```
const client = new orgPackageDefinition.OrganizationService(
  "bbl-org-server.default.svc.cluster.local:50051",
  grpc.credentials.createInsecure()
);
```

But it is not connecting to the server and I get a response as

```
{
    "message": {
        "code": 14,
        "details": "No connection established",
        "metadata": {},
        "progress": "PROCESSED"
    }
}
```

Please help me.

I have created a headless service and I'm able to ping the bbl-org-server from bbl-org-client. But, I'm not able to connect with gRPC client.

Comment: Have you tried running this in a simpler environment, like plain Docker containers?  What does the server code look like, and is it actually listening on `0.0.0.0:50051`?

Comment: You are great. I found it. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Add a prefix for the Kubernetes service so it knows that is a grpc port for the service. In the examples below you can see the difference between a http and a grpc:

```yaml
spec:
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 8383
    - name: grpc
      port: 9090
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 9090
```

Comment: The `name:` of a port doesn't matter in standard Kubernetes.  The Kubernetes networking layer doesn't look at the contents of a TCP stream at all.  HTTP, gRPC, binary database protocols, and other network traffic are all handled the same way.